# Question on Aleo zkVM

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Can we use array as the input of a transition/function? Just like:\

```
transition testarr(arr: [u32; 3]) {

}
```

I saw some tutorials that have examples of this but now the Aleo seems not to support this grammar.

Comment: This is a programming question, and as such [off-topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You could try asking on StackOverflow, though given how nice this software seems to be you might be better off trying to contact their community directly. There might be a forum, Discord, or some such.